# GNU C Cross-compiler: Cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, unix, gcc, busybox

I've been trying to compile busybox from source for ttylinux x64 I'm currently.. dealing with. Because of some king of bug (very similar to described [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/ptxdist@pengutronix.de/msg02015.html)) I'm forced to use cross compiler.

But this thing refuses to work. When I try to run it:

```
$ /mnt/hdd/cross-compiler-x86_64/bin/x86_64-gcc --version
```

I get:

```
-bash: /mnt/hdd/cross-compiler-x86_64/bin/x86_64-gcc: cannot execute binary file
```

This is different diagnostic outputs:

```
$ ldd /mnt/hdd/cross-compiler-x86_64/bin/x86_64-gcc
not a dynamic executable

$ uname -mpi
x86_64 unknown unknown

$ uname -a
Linux ttylinux_host 3.7.1 #1 SMP Mon May 27 14:31:18 MST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ objdump -f /mnt/hdd/cross-compiler-x86_64/bin/x86_64-gcc
/mnt/hdd/cross-compiler-x86_64/bin/x86_64-gcc: file format elf32-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x08048188
```

Can anyone help me with this matter? I do believe x64 should have no problem running i386 code?

BTW: cross compiler originates from [here](http://landley.net/aboriginal/downloads/binaries/)

Comment: `file /mnt/hdd/cross-compiler-x86_64/bin/x86_64-gcc`?

Comment: Sorry, no such thing on that distro. file: command not found

Comment: Is the filesystem mounted `noexec` by any chance?

Comment: Nope, mount | grep hdd returns: (rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really looks like a kernel that is configured for pure 64-bit userspace, no i386 support.

This would be `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION` in the kernel config. Check `/proc/config.gz` to confirm.

Comment: You are probably right: in ttylinux this option is not set, while in oracle it is 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

What is the origin of your cross compiler? Cross-native compilers are notorious for having dependencies on the architecture of the build-host of the toolchain. These go un-noticed until the toolchain is moved to a different architecture. 
You can move the runtime binary for any of the executables in the toolchain to some host that has the 'file' utility. This will probably tell you quite a lot, although the message from *ldd* is already suggesting that the binary is unacceptable to run on the present (or any?) architecture. The utility *nm* run against the binaries in the toolchain may be useful. If they all complain that the file(s) is/are not executable, then I think you will need to re-acquire a working toolchain.

Comment: Ok, I've tried nm on this thing: it gives pretty much output with hex numbers and lib calls (I assume), and since I don't know what should I've been looking for I consider it's executable. I'll install ubuntu and run `file` on this binary later

Comment: OK, `file` thing been used: x86_64-gcc is sym link for x86_64-cc. The later is `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not striped`. What is more important, it actually works on Oracle Linux 6 (x64) and responds to `--version`. The reason it refuses to run on ttylinux x64 is mystery to me.

Comment: Puzzling, indeed. From reading about the origin of your cross toolchain, it sounds like it may be tightly targeted to a very specific architecture. I think one can only guess that your ttylinux is built to only run 64bit binaries, perhaps being part of the virtualization expected by the toolchain builder system.

Comment: It seems so. Kernel config suggests this may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer:

```
 Try this:
 readelf --headers /mnt/hdd/cross-compiler-x86_64/bin/x86_64-gcc

 look for a line in the output that is something like:
 [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-blahblah]

 Do you have the /lib/ld-blahblah file (for whatever blahblah really is) in the runtime environment? Most probably not. Make a symlink from what you see in the output above to what is actually on the machine.
```

To help clarify your question, you should make more clear about:

```
 Are you saying that ttylinux-x86_64 has gcc but it doesn't work? Or that ttylinux does not have gcc and you are NFS-mounting one?
```

And a hint to get better help than from here:

```
 Wouldn't it help if you asked the ttylinux maintainer?
```

Comment: 1. I found no such thing in readelf output. Everything seems legit. 2. ttylinux should have some built-in compiler, but due to a bug I cannot compile busybox using it. I was able to find out that using cross-compiler for this matter should solve this problem though. So I've downloaded and unpacked it to local mounted partition (since '/' partition is actually very small). 3. It's pretty small community so it would take much time to get response, and since I was not sure if it's this exact distro problem and not just me being stupid with linux I've decided to ask here.

Comment: 1. If the file is an elf executable you will find a line for the 'program interpreter'in that output, without it the executable is not "legit". 2. ttylinux-x86_64 does have gcc, if it isn't working then get the latest ttylinux-x86_64 and if that doesn't work you should send something to the maintainer so he can reproduce and fix it. Also, if you are trying to use gcc in the running ttylinux environment to make code to also run in the ttylnux environment, then you are NOT dealing with a cross-compiler; it is just a compiler.

Comment: 3. So the ttylinux maintainer finds this post on the Internet and makes an account here to help you while wondering why you don't tell him about the problem so he can reproduce the problem and fix it for everyone and maybe help you better understand things. Clue: I am the ttylinux maintainer. It would be best if you email me; I'll do what I can to help.

Comment: 1. Oops -- The 'program interpreter' is true for dynamically linked programs. I don't know how that works for statically linked programs. When I get back to my ttylinux dev environment, I'll look into it.

Comment: So, as I understand it looks like BusyBox problem: there is a thing when you specify cross compiler prefix to be used during `make`, and if it's empty, it passes some dummy thing instead, and this dummy thing can't take parameter `-o` which passed to it. That's the reason I went all this cross compiler path instead.